# How can I this so only the best performing company is shown for each year?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, filter, subquery

I've been working on this single SQL statement for a couple of days now & I can't seem to get this done.
With some help from friends/family, I managed to get the statement close to completion, but there's a vital part still missing & I can't figure out how to do this exactly.

This is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    T1.Jaar, 
    T1.CompanyName, 
    CONCAT('€ ', CONVERT(money,T1.Kost)) AS 'Hoogste Prijs'
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  
        Year(OrderDate) AS 'Jaar',
        CompanyName,
        SUM(Freight) AS 'Kost'
    FROM Orders
    JOIN Shippers S ON ShipVia = S.ShipperID
    GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), CompanyName
    ) T1
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT  
        Year(OrderDate) AS 'Jaar',
        CompanyName,
        SUM(Freight) AS 'Kost'
    FROM Orders
    JOIN Shippers S ON ShipVia = S.ShipperID
    GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), CompanyName
    ) T2 ON T1.CompanyName = T2.CompanyName
ORDER BY Jaar
```

Which returns me the following resultset:
[image: Resultset]

Now, for the part that I can't figure out:
Using the above statement, I need to expand it so that I only get the highest value for "Hoogste Prijs" for each year.
So in the end, my resultset should look like this:

```
+------+------------------+---------------+
| Jaar |   CompanyName    | Hoogste Prijs |
+------+------------------+---------------+
| 1996 | Federal Shipping | € 4233.78     |
| 1997 | United Package   | € 12374.04    |
| 1998 | United Package   | € 12122.14    |
+------+------------------+---------------+
```

From what I understand, I shouldn't be far off from the solution, but I can't seem to find it at all.

Comment: Do you really need that self-join? What's the result if you remove that?

Comment: Well, I can get this same result set without using any subqueries, but I was told by my sister that in order to get the final result, I need to join this temp table with itself so I can compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
with CompanyPerYear as ( -- this is your query, I removed the self-join since both give the same results
    SELECT  
        Year(OrderDate) AS 'Jaar',
        CompanyName,
        SUM(Freight) AS 'Kost'
    FROM Orders
    JOIN Shippers S ON ShipVia = S.ShipperID
    GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), CompanyName   
),
cte as (
    SELECT
        *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Jaar ORDER BY Kost DESC)
    FROM CompanyPerYear
)
SELECT
    Jaar,
    CompanyName,
    CONCAT('€ ', CONVERT(money,Kost)) AS 'Hoogste Prijs'
FROM cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm :)
However, is there any chance you could help me out with putting all 3 queries in a single query? (Through subqueries), as this is for a school assignment & I don't want it to be too obvious that I the answer given to me, also, could you somewhat explain the workings of the first two parts (CompanyPerYear & cte) for me?

Comment: You may want to start with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Aha I see, now I get it :) Thanks bro :)